# extracting images and their label one by one from ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

so I imported my dataset(38 classes) for validation using ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory

```
valid = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory="dataset/valid", target_size=(224,224))
```

and i wanted to pick each image and its label one by one. For example i want to pick the first image and it's label

i tried this

```
for img, lbl in valid:
    print(lbl)
    break
```

i get the image but for the label i just get an array of shape (32,38) with 0 and 1s

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Is there a way to get the label of this picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) might help you with this question. More specifically, the default arguments from `tf.keras.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`:

```
flow_from_directory(
    directory, target_size=(256, 256), color_mode='rgb', classes=None,
    class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=None,
    save_to_dir=None, save_prefix='', save_format='png',
    follow_links=False, subset=None, interpolation='nearest'
)
```

The class mode is categorical, so your labels will come as one-hot encoded matrices. The default batch size is 32, so when you iterate, 32 one-hot encoded rows will be fetched every time. This is what you're getting.

To access the labels, you can index the list of all labels of your dataset:

```
valid.labels[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

the output of the generator is of the form (batch_size, images, labels). Since you did not specify the batch_size it defaults to 32. Also you did not specify the class_mode so that defaults to categorical. What this means is your labels will be one-hot encoded. Each label will be a vector of length 38. Therefore your labels will be of the form (batch_size, 38).
Now you probably want to show the actual NAME of the class
versus it's categorical value. You can achieve this using  class_dict=valid.class_indices.
This returns a dictionary of the form {class_name: integer_value} where integer value is the value of the integer associated with the class name. Some other useful attributes
of the generator are  labels= valid.labels which is a list all all the labels and
file_names= valid.filenames  which is a list of all the file_names. Now if you want to
print out all the label information use the code below

```
source_dir=r'dataset/valid' # set this to the path of the directory with the images
batch_size=32  # specify the desired batch size
valid=ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(source_dir, class_mode='categorical',batch_size=batch_size, target_size=(224,224) )
val_labels=valid.labels
file_names=valid.filenames
gen_length=len(val_labels)
print ('There are a total of ', gen_length, 'files in the specified directory')
class_dict=valid.class_indices
new_dict={}
for key,value in class_dict.items(): # reverse the dictionary show it is in the form {integer label, class_name}
    new_dict[value]=key  
for i in range (gen_length):
    file_count=  (i+1)* batch_size
    if file_count>=gen_length:    
        j_end=gen_length- i* batch_size # cut off printing because we have used all the labels
    else:
        j_end=batch_size
    files, labels = next(valid) # fetches next batch of 32 files and labels
    print (' For batch ',i, ' labels are:')
    print ('{0:^20s} {1:^14s}'.format('CLASS', 'CLASS NUMBER'))
    for j in range (j_end):
        label=np.argmax(labels[j])
        class_name= new_dict[label]
        print('{0:^20s} {1:^14s}'.format(class_name, str(label)))
    if file_count>=gen_length:
        break
```